# How to detect when a session ends

Tags: php, javascript

Is there a way to detect when someone leaves your site? So far I know about using `ignore_user_abort()` but thats about as far as I've gotten.

The reason I need to know this is because I need a script to execute upon someone leaving the site.

Comment: You could keep track of the last time their session_id was used. Then when it goes past a certain threshold, run your script. Or you can detect with javascript when they try to leave your site. I'm sure you have seen the annoying popups that try to get you to stay on web pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Record a timestamp in a database for each user and update this upon each page load (or through AJAX).

When the last updated timestamp is older than a cetain amount of time (30 mins?) you can consider they've left the site and do your code, deleting the entry afterwards.

- Idea: a "user" could be a primary key made up of their IP and user agent as an MD5 hash for example.

Comment: Wouldn't I need Cron for such a thing?

Comment: Yes to run through old entries you probably would. You can't rely on catching people leaving through javascript.

Comment: I'm kind of back to my original problem though. I wouldn't want cron to run after say, 2 minutes of them being on the site it pretty much needs to be individual if that makes sense.

Comment: php has a session gc function that is called from time to time, which is used for cleaning out old sessions.  Some session backends will ignore expired sessions on load.  No cron needed. http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability

Comment: The cron runs at a set time, say every 15 minutes. All it does is look up old entries e.g. `SELECT * FROM users_browsing WHERE browse_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTES` then for each result you can do your code.

Comment: @fire - genious, didn't think of that one.

Comment: @fire: I don't like your idea of creating a hash from IP and UA. We have a number of people browsing the web via NAT on a single IP address using identical browser builds. Hashes should **NOT** be used to create unique ids/keys. That is not what they are for. There's no guarantee that different inputs will not create the same output.

Answer (score 1):

1) I've found the [Session Timeout Warning PHP Example with jQuery/JS](http://www.jensbits.com/2009/09/07/session-timeout-warning-php-example-with-jqueryjs/)  article

2) [Session timeout in PHP](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/124500) thread

3) Also [article on how to do it with jQuery and ColdFusion](http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=572)

Answer (score 0):

Due to the stateless nature of http, there isn't an easy way to tell when someone leaves a site.  It is possible to trigger onUnload when they leave a page, but this also fires as they navigate from page to page on your site.

- Mozilla's Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload
- MS's Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907(v=vs.85).aspx

Normally a session is setup to just expire when the user hasn't been seen in X minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I can be done easily using javascript, check this solution

```
  <body onbeforeunload="winCloseFunc();"> =)
```