# How to Pop up an alert when an http session expires

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, struts2

I have a requirement in the project that i am working on. When a user's session expires, i need to automatically forward the user to the login page or pop an alert telling him that his session has expired. When the user clicks Ok, he is forwarded to the login page. Please how do i achieve this.

Comment: check this and see if helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404735/how-to-detect-when-a-session-ends

Comment: I have visited the link. i am using jsp and i don't want to interact with the database on this. Is there a better a way.

Comment: oh, my mistake, didnt see. sry

Answer (score 1):

1 Set javascript timer with ajax call to server.

2 Check session on the server side. Return error if session expired

3 In your .ajax error section send user to login page

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
    ...........
    error: function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         //load login page
        }
    });
}, 1000)
```

Comment: well said, though this will try to pull the response, if you have the option you can use server push, where server will automatically send you the information when session timeout happens

Comment: Also if session has expired just after one fetch session response call then user will have an invalid session from that moment till the next call is made, this can lead to troubles depending on the application